# How can i achieve a rotate animation in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm animating some css styles with this:

```
$(".left").animate({
    left: '300px',
    width: '300px',
    height: '300px',
    top: '25px'
}, 1000,'easeInOutQuint', function() {
});
```

I tried to add a `transform` property but it doesn't seem to work. Any solution?
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3bWZ/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solutions, and the one that worked in my case, was using a small jQuery plugin for rotation that can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add quotes to the transform property, like:

```
$(".left").animate({
    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(180deg)',
    '-moz-transform': 'rotate(180deg)',
    '-ms-transform': 'rotate(180deg)',
    '-o-transform': 'rotate(180deg)',
    'transform': 'rotate(180deg)'
});
```

EDIT: I tested this and found it not working. Apparantly jQuery doesn't support CSS3 tags in the "animation" function. You probably need a plugin unless someone else has a better idea.

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work. i added a fiddle to my question for details.

Comment: Yes I tested it and it doesn't work. This was just from the top of my head. It does work with .css({}) but than it doesn't animate of course. Interesting too see a good solution

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to add a property not used such as text-indent and then increment its value. Set some value for text-indent in the css class '.last'. Check the below code sample.

```
$('.left').animate({
    left: '300px',
    width: '300px',
    height: '300px',
    top: '25px',
    textIndent: '0px'
},
{
    step:function(now,fx) {
        $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)'); 
    }
});
```

Hope this would solve your problem. Or you could simply use the css3 animation property.

Comment: You can use any unharmed property. For example z-index. But that wont support negative values. Or you don't want to use negative values with z-index